# 75 GB is missing under 'Other volumes' category

Tags: macos, catalina, apfs

[image]

I think I might have created a partition a while ago for Boot Camp. Can you please help how to get the space back?

Comment: The APFS container accommodates three different "Macintosh HD - Data" volumes while it should contain only one of them. Please list the content of the Data volumes.

Comment: @ankii I have never seen **three** "Macintosh HD - Data" APFS volumes in one container... :-(

Comment: Also add the output of `diskutil apfs list` and `diskutil apfs listVolumeGroups` entered in Terminal.app **as formatted text** (no images)!

Comment: @klanomath APFS volume groups are sadly not mentioned anywhere in the current version of the official spec (2019-02-07). Do you know of any good resources that detail them, perhaps with data structure definitions?

Answer (score 0):

First, nothing is really missing. An APFS container composed in this manner looks like this in Terminal **and** Disk Utility.

A standard boot volume APFS container in Catalina accommodates five volumes:

- a preboot volume (your disk1s2)
- a recovery volume (your disk1s3)
- a VM volume (your disk1s4)
- a read-only mounted system volume (your disk1s7)
- a read-write mounted data volume (probably your disk1s1)

The last two are combined in one APFS volume group.

---

Your container *disk0s2* houses **two additional data volumes**  (*disk1s5* and *disk1s6*) though. Both adhere to the standard naming scheme of the default read-write mounted data volume of an APFS boot container: [name_of_main_volume] & [ - Data]. The larger of the two additional data volumes (*disk1s6*) is not mounted and therefore "missing".

Considering the size of the various data volumes *disk1s6* is probably your former data volume. I assume that it was replaced by the very small disk1s1 data volume in the APFS volume group accidentally.

---

To solve your problem additional info (as stated in my comments) is required.